# XCode Reusing UITableViewCells in Storyboard

Tags: xcode, uitableview, reuseidentifier

I have a UITableViewCell in my project that I want to reuse in a few UITableViews. Is there a way to reuse them without setting up UILabels, etc each time in the Storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndex, you can refer to the custom cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
CustomCell *cell = ...
cell.labelName.text = ...;
Return cell;
```

}

Comment: My question is more of a storyboard question I think.  How do I reuse a cell without having to set the layout every time.

Comment: Create a class that subclasses uitableviewcell, and refer to that for each prototype cell

Comment: That doesn't specify the layout of UI elements though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your UITableViewCell class and register it for your tables

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:<RegisteredClass> forCellReuseIdentifier:<ReuseIdentifier>];
}
```